# Mock a function called by other function which has been already mocked

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermockito

I am trying to mock static function(getBatchId() and sendPost()) for following code  :

```
public void doPost(){      
String batchId = Utility.getBatchId();
                    Post post = new Post(batchId, userId, message);
                    String postJson = Utility.toJson(post);
                          Chat.sendPost(url,postJson)
}
```

Unit testcase code for above method :

```
 mockStatic(Utility.class);
        when(Utility.getBatchId()).thenReturn("demoBatchId1234");

        mockStatic(Chat.class);
        when(Chat.sendPost(url,postJson))
                .thenReturn(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> HttpResponse.create()));
```

I am getting following exception at ***when(Utility.getBatchId()).thenReturn("demoBatchId1234");*** while running test case :

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException:  when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
>   For example:
>       when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:

1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.    Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.    Mocking methods
   declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.

Comment: could you provide the whole test class with the imports, and so on... where does the `mockStatic` method comes from? Do you use PowerMockito? In that case, do you use the `PrepareForTest` annotation? See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21116014/2891426

Comment: Thanks @Nagy Vilmos .... problem has been solved

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mock static methods from different class then you need to prepare all those classes for test using Junit like :

```
@PrepareForTest({Chat.class,Utility.class})
```